# Proper way to write a acronym that's become a verb

Tags: verbs, tenses, acronyms

In the Unix programming world there's a command called [`cd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)). It stands for `Change Directory`.

From what I can research it's at least 35 years old.

I often hear at my job "Then we'll cd into ".

With that usage established I was wondering if there's an established standard for how to specify a past tense use for this term.

I've tried using `Target directory couldn't be cd'd` but I'm unsure how that sounds to a general audience.

Comment: @Glorfindel I do see where that post is coming from. At the same time I wonder if `cd` is so common (at least in my niche corner of the world) that it's no longer jargon and there's a common use.

Comment: I think you might **say** "cee-dee'd" but wouldn't write it, at least not formally. The linked post mentions a verb *lase* as back-formed from *laser,* although *lasered* is not uncommon. And people are definitely *tasered* and not *tased.* I suppose there is scope for that older question to get new answers based on recent practice.

Comment: I don't agree with the contraction of the past tense. I would write it cd'ed instead.  Although recent research shows that apostrophes should not be used unless your argument is a single character.

Comment: Consider: *couldn't cd to target directory*.

Comment: Changing the tense of commands tends to be awkward. This may be partly because commands are program names (nouns), even though they are treated as actions (verbs). Another possible reason is the spelling of the command string - modifying the command name to form a past tense results in a string that doesn't run the intended program. These probably aren't *English* words (yet).

Comment: I think you have to choose between writing for a very technical audience (where jargon forms welcome shortcuts) and writing for a general audience. One writing might not serve both populations.  If it must, I would certainly lean towards good English like "Couldn't change into the target directory" and let the techies think "oh, yeah, cd."

Comment: CD as Change Directory is a lot more than 35 years old but still pure jargon to most people - which makes your question as much about the nature of the ‘general audience’ as the real meaning of the words.

‘Target directory couldn't be cd’d’ isn’t literally ‘… couldn't be Change Directoried’ is it? It’s ‘… couldn't be ‘… Changed’ or ‘…  reached using CD’

Unfamiliarity is a stumbling block in all cases and you’re coining a new phrase so there’s no real way round that. CD’d will be what many expect but it’ll always be at least as hard to just defend as to attack…

…

Comment: CD’d is a text-book case of slipping into abbreviation and trying to climb the other side without looking in the rear-view mirror, let alone changing gear.

The apostrophe never had a place and the ‘d’ wasn’t needed, either; to anyone half-way in the know ‘Target directory couldn't be CD’ would mean the same, after hearing it twice… Past-tensing complicates it and the basic problem is seen more in plurals eg, VIP, GP, MP; usually given an ’s’ and often an apostrophe, but never in fact need either

The real problem is that the actual message is ‘Could not CD to Target Directory.’